# Is there an error with my code here? C, Queues Data Structure

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I'm working on a question involving Stacks and Queue data structures using LinkedList from my school.

I've approached the question using Queue and it still couldn't work and I would love an outside view on my code to see where is wrong.

I've written my question, given code and my own attempt below.

It's a pretty long question, hope I've done enough for it to be clear to you guys helping me:)

Let me know if there's any uncertainty.

I've suspected it lies in determining the outcome once I searched through the entire queue to find a partner.

Thanks for helping a noob out :) My judgment is probably blurred at this point to see it

**My goal / question** 
: It is to write a function called balanced()

prototype: int balanced(char *expression);

The function deals with brackets and tells me if it's balanced (return 0) or not (return -1).

Example of balanced expressions are:

- ()
- ([])
- {[]}

Example of unbalanced expressions are:

- {{)]
- [({{)])

**Expected results**

Enter an expression, terminated by a newline:

[({{{}}})[[]]{}({})]

The expression is balanced.

Enter an expression, terminated by a newline:

{1+2+{5}*[6+x]+{4+5}(3+2)}

The expression is balanced.

Enter an expression, terminated by a newline:

[5[3(3)4{()]}]

The expression is not balanced.

**Right here below is the code that I've written and tried for the function: balanced().

The code runs, there's no error prompt**

```
int balanced(char *expression)
{

    Queue q1, q2;

    q1.ll.head = NULL;
    q1.ll.tail = NULL;
    q1.ll.size = 0;

    q2.ll.head = NULL;
    q2.ll.tail = NULL;
    q2.ll.size = 0;

    // transfer all them brackets into a queue called q1
    while ( *expression != '0' )
    {
        if ( *expression != '{' || *expression != '}' || *expression != '[' || *expression != ']' || *expression != '(' || *expression != ')' )
        {
            enqueue( &q1, *expression );
        }
        expression++;
    }
    // at this point, my queue is pure brackets

    char interested, partner, partnerSearch;
    int innerCount, outerCount, almighty;
    innerCount = 0;
    outerCount = 0;
    almighty = -1;

    while (  outerCount != q1.ll.size )
    {
        if( !isEmptyQueue( &q1 ) )
        {
            interested = dequeue( &q1 ); // pick a guy

            // i'll next try to find a match for the bracket by peekQueue
            if ( interested == '{' )
            {
                partner = '}';
            }
            else if ( interested == '[' )
            {
                partner = ']';
            }
            else if ( interested == '(' )
            {
                partner = ')';
            }
            // at this point, they know who their ideal partner is

            // I'll need to run it by a loop for the queue
            innerCount = 0;

            while ( innerCount <  (q1.ll.size - 1) )
            {
                partnerSearch = dequeue( &q1 );

                if( partner != partnerSearch )
                {
                    enqueue( &q1, partnerSearch );
                }
                // so if partner == partnerSearch, it will successfully get dequeue
                // if not they queue back
                innerCount++;
            }
        }
        else
            almighty = 0;
    }

    if ( almighty == 0 )
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does your code work as expected or not?

Comment: I think you have done a pretty good job writing this question but this "...  and it still couldn't work" needs to be better explained. What is not working? Give an example of input that results in wrong output

Comment: Please show a reasonable instance where the code actually fails to give the expected output.

Comment: This is far too much code to expect us to debug it for you. But I would recommend writing print functions for your data structures. Furthermore, study [mre]

Comment: OT: This looks suspicious: `while ( *expression != '0' )` do you really want to iterate until character `0`? Maybe you want to check for the null-terminator: `'\0'`

Comment: @klutt alright! I'll look into that. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the feedback guys :) I know it is a bad answer, my bad. Yea I'll go look into producing a short question next time, include what didn't work i.e. wrong output, more specificity of the problem for future questions.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
    if ( *expression != '{' || *expression != '}' || *expression != '[' || *expression != ']' || *expression != '(' || *expression != ')' )
    {
        enqueue( &q1, *expression );
    }
```

is wrong.

Assume that `*expression`is an `'a'`. Then the expression will be true.

Assume that `*expression`is an `'{'`. Then the expression will be true.

Assume that `*expression`is an `'}'`. Then the expression will be true.

In other words - it will always be true.

You probably want to use `==` instead of `!=`

And as written in a comment by @DavidRanieri:

```
while ( *expression != '0' )
```

is wrong.

It shall be

```
while ( *expression != '\0' )
```

or simply

```
while ( *expression )
```

In general it seems to me that your approach is too complicated.

I would use a **stack** for this job. All opening brackets are pushed to the stack. When you have a closing bracket, pop from the stack and check that the two brackets have the same type.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
for ( each character C in expression )
{
   if (C is an opening bracket)
   {
       stack->push(C)
   }
   else if (C is a closing bracket)
   {
       if (stack is empty) return -1

       TMP = stack->pop;
       if (C == '}' and TMP != '{') return -1
       if (C == ']' and TMP != '[') return -1
       ... same for other bracket types ...
   }
}

if (stack is empty) return 0

return -1
```

In real C code this could be:

```
int check_brackets(char* expression)
{
    stack_t s = {NULL};
    char c = *expression++;
    while(c)
    {
        if (c == '{' || c == '[' || c == '(')
        {
            stack_push(&s, c);
        }
        else if (c == '}' || c == ']' || c == ')')
        {
            if (stack_empty(&s)) return -1;

            char tmp = stack_pop(&s);
            if (
                (c == '}' && tmp != '{') ||
                (c == ']' && tmp != '[') ||
                (c == ')' && tmp != '(')
               )
            {
                stack_free(&s);
                return -1;
            }
        }
        c = *expression++;
    }
    if (stack_empty(&s)) return 0;

    stack_free(&s);
    return -1;
}
```

(note: implementation of stack_t and related functions not shown)

Comment: I will also use a stack, (well ... two stacks: operands and operators)  the [Shunting-Yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) is suitable for this

Comment: @DavidRanieri As I understand the question, OP is only to find out whether an expression is balanced. So there is no need for multiple stacks, nor is it necessary to save operands and operators

Comment: well, based on the expression on his post `({1+2+{5}*[6+x]+{4+5}(3+2)})` soon or later he will have to use it, operator precedence and things like that requires (or is better managed) with two stacks, but yeah, that's another question ...

Comment: @DavidRanieri If OP was to evaluate the expressions then yes! But that doesn't seem to be the task.

Comment: I totally agree!